# How to use multiple tables for authenticating users in django rest?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Hi I am starting a new project and i need to create separate tables for user(CustomUser model) and vendor(Vendor model) and authenticate user  from CustomeUser model and vendor from Vendor model

I know that by using AUTH_USER_MODEL we can change default User model but i need to use two different tables for two different type of users and authenticate them

If there any way to do this or have any suggestion  please let me know

Comment: Really suggest you to create base class for authentication only and two different classes for getting your data based on user types

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I Would suggest you to Keep only one authentication model and you can use my_user_type to decide user role either vendor else..and respective vendor and cus_user fields

```
  class User(AbstractUser):
        vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vndor, null=True, blank=True, related_name='referral')              
        cus_user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, null=True, blank=True, related_name='referral')
        USERTYPE= (
            ('v', 'Vendor'),
            ('u', 'User'),
        )      
        my_user_type = models.CharField(choices=USERTYPE, max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)
        enter code here
```